# Generic linear equation system alignment

Tags: align, alignment

Using this code

```
\begin{align*} 
  a_{11}x_1 + \ldots + a_{1n}x_n &= b_1\\ 
  \vdots + \vdots + \vdots &= \vdots\\ 
  a_{n1}x_1 + \ldots + a_{nn}x_n &= b_n
\end{align*}
```

gives

[image]

and so I tried to add more `&` around the `+` for them to be aligned correctly, i.e.

```
\begin{align*} 
  a_{11}x_1 &+ \ldots &+ a_{1n}x_n &= b_1\\ 
  \vdots &+ \vdots &+ \vdots &= \vdots\\ 
  a_{n1}x_1 &+ \ldots &+ a_{nn}x_n &= b_n
\end{align*}
```

which sadly doesn't yield the wanted behavior:

[image]

---

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or how I can achieve that all the `+` are aligned correctly. Can you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use the `alignat` environment instead of `align`:

[image]

To center the `vdots` you can use a `\makebox` which I have wrapped in the `\CenterWithin` macro.  This yields:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `alignat` environment produces *pairs* of `r`ight/`l` alignment, hence the need for a double `&&` to produce left aligment (i.e., skip over the `r` column).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{5}
  a_{11}x_1 &{}+ \ldots &&{}+ a_{1n}x_n &&= b_1\\ 
     \vdots &{}+ \vdots &&{}+    \vdots &&= \vdots\\ 
  a_{n1}x_1 &{}+ \ldots &&{}+ a_{nn}x_n &&= b_n
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

### Code: Centered vdots

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*{\CenterWithin}[2]{%
    %% #1 = content to typset
    %% #2 = content whose width is used to determine where the center is
    \makebox[\widthof{$#2$}][c]{$#1$}%
}
\newcommand*{\VdotsC}{\CenterWithin{\vdots}{\ldots}}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{5}
  a_{11}x_1 &{}+ \ldots  &&{}+ a_{1n}x_n &&= b_1\\ 
  \CenterWithin{\vdots}{a_{11}x_1} &{}+ \VdotsC 
       &&{}+ \CenterWithin{\vdots}{a_{1n}x_n} &&= \CenterWithin{\vdots}{b_1} \\ 
  a_{n1}x_1 &{}+ \ldots  &&{}+ a_{nn}x_n &&= b_n
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will accept it as soon as I can. Just another little question: do you maybe also know how the `\vdots` can be centered between the `+`?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow: See updated answer.

Comment: The systeme package, written by C. tellechea, alias unbonpetit, does that very well. A 8-page documentation written in french provides many outputs available with this package.